# How to return `false` if item you want to delete isn't in list

Tags: c++, linked-list, return

I am trying to delete from a linked list and return `true` if it was successfully deleted and return `false` if the number in the liked list is not in the list. The problem is that I don't know how I would return `false` if the item is not in the list. I don't even know how i would check if it is in the list. Please help.

```
bool list::deleteElement(int element)
{
   node *curr, *prev;
   prev = NULL;
   if(head!=NULL)
   {
      for(curr=head; curr->item!=element&&curr!=NULL;curr= curr->next)
      {
         prev=curr;
      } 
      if(curr!=NULL)
      {
         if(prev==NULL)
         {
            head = head->next;
            delete curr;
            numberofelements--;
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
            prev->next = curr ->next;
            delete curr;
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
}//end of function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty close to being correct.

You don't need to explicitly check if `head` is NULL.  Your logic can handle that case implicitly.  Once you eliminate that test, then the `return false;` will be the last line of your function.

You need to reverse your check in the for loop so that you don't try to dereference a NULL pointer:

```
for (curr = head; curr != NULL && curr->item != element; curr = curr->next)
```

You need to decrement `numberofelements` in the else-case when `prev != NULL` too.

You can "factor out" the `delete`, the `numberofelements--;` and the `return true;` from the if-else statements when `curr != NULL`.

Here's how I would write it:

```
bool list::deleteElement(int element)
{
  node *curr = head, *prev = NULL;

  for (; curr != NULL && curr->item != element; prev = curr, curr = curr->next);

  if (curr == NULL)  // element not found
    return false;

  if (prev == NULL)
    head = head->next;
  else
    prev->next = curr->next;

  delete curr;
  --numberofelements;

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues that I see:

1. You don't have a `return` statement when `head == NULL`. That's a problem. It is undefined behavior.
2. The check `curr->item!=element&&curr!=NULL;` in the `for` loop is not right. When `curr == NULL`, you will run into undefined behavior since you are dereferencing the pointer first and checking whether it is NULL second. That should be `curr != NULL && curr->item != element`.
3. You are not decrementing the number of elements when `prev != NULL`.

Here's the updated function:

```
bool list::deleteElement(int element)
{
   node *curr, *prev;
   prev = NULL;

   if(head==NULL)
   {
      // Empty list. Return right away with false.
      return false;
   }

   for(curr=head; curr!=NULL && curr->item!=element; curr= curr->next)
   {
      prev=curr;
   } 
   if(curr!=NULL)
   {
      // The number of elements needs to be decremented
      // regardless of whether prev is NULL or not.
      numberofelements--;
      if(prev==NULL)
      {
         head = head->next;
         delete curr;
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         prev->next = curr ->next;
         delete curr;
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}//end of function
```